# Palindromo recursivo C

Tags: c, recursão

Minhas funções não estão funcionando corretamente, sempre o programa me fala que não é palíndromo, para qualquer situação. Segue o código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


int inverte (char *n, int y, int aux) {

     if (y <= aux) return 1;

     else {
         if (n[y] != n[aux]) return 0;

         return inverte(n, y-1, aux+1);
     } 
}

 int palindromo (char *n) {
     int aux1, x = 0;

     aux1 = inverte(n, strlen(n), x);

     if (aux1 == 1) printf("Eh palindromo");

     else printf("Nao eh palindromo");

 }


 int main() {

     char m[30] = {"anna"};

     palindromo(m);

     return 0; 
 }
```

Comment: Isto ocorre porque este algoritmo é claramente inadequado para fazer recursão. Até é possível, mas é muito pior, confuso e acaba gerando erros. Eu sei que provavelmente alguém mandou fazer assim, mas é um erro. Pra aprender, é melhor aprender fazer certo, fazer recursão onde ela é adequada. Tentar fazer onde não cabe aprende-se zero ou desaprende. Toda vez que tem que passar uma variável de controle é caso para fazer iteração.

Comment: Só me deram como enunciado a função, int palindromo (char *n), na vdd estou um pouco perdido em recursão

Answer (score 6):

A resposta da Taisbevalle é linda, porém senti que não tocou onde o Marcelo de Sousa cometeu seu engano.

### Strings

Basicamente, o problema não foi no entendimento de recursão, mas na manipulação da string. Em C, uma string é iniciada pelo índice zero e finalizada pelo caracter `'\0'`. Assim, a palavra de testes de palíndromo `anna` tem os seguintes caracteres, nas seguintes posições:

```
[0] -> 'a'
[1] -> 'n'
[2] -> 'n'
[3] -> 'a'
[4] -> '\0'
```

O quinto caracter é o terminador da string, necessário em C para [indicar seu final](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string).

A função `strlen` conta quantos caracteres há em determinada string.  `anna` tem claramente 4 caracteres. Então, o retorno de `strlen("anna")` é 4.

A função `inverte`, ele recebe 3 parâmetros:

1. `n`, que é a string que perguntamos se é palíndromo ou não
2. `y`, de cujo nome eu não consigo arrancar um significa, mas que no código é algo como a base para fazer a comparação do lado direito da string
3. `aux`, o índice auxiliar que vai sendo percorrido, da esquerda para a direita, para determinar se a string é palíndromo

Na chamada inicial de `inverte`, são passados os seguintes valores:

1. `n` ==> a string em questão
2. `y` ==> o tamanho da string passada como `n`
3. `aux` ==> `0`, a posição inicial da string

A comparação dentro de `inverte` ocorre sobre o índice esquerdo (`aux`) e o índice direito (`y`) da seguinte maneira:

```
if (n[y] != n[aux]) return 0;
```

Voltando ao caso da `anna`; o tamanho da `anna` é 4, então o valor inicial de `y` é 4. No primeiro passo da recursão, os valores sendo comparados são os seguintes:

```
if (n[4] != n[0]) return 0;
```

Lembrando-se da decomposição inicial que eu fiz para a palavra `anna`, na posição `0` temos o caracter `'a'`, enquanto que na posição `4` temos o caracter `'\0'`! Então, substituindo pelos caracteres sendo comparados:

```
if ('\0' != 'a') return 0;
```

E `'\0'` é direferente de `'a'`, portanto ele sairá da função nesse ponto. Sempre.

Quase qualquer que seja a string passada para a função `palindromo` (que por sua vez chama a função `inverte`), ela comparará o primeiro caracter dessa string com `'\0'`, o que sempre será distinto; a única string que essa função reconhece corretamente como palíndromo é a string vazia, pois assim a comparação do primeiro caracter (fim de string, `'\0'`) e o fim de string dá igual e `inverte` detecta corretamente que `""` é palíndromo. Então, nosso problema está ou na interpretação do índice `y` ou no valor inicial de `y`. Então, fiz duas sugestões de correção para isso.

Note que, nas sugestões, adicionei alguns casos a mais de teste.

### Sugestão 1: passar a posição da última letra válida

Nessa sugestão, altero como a função `palindromo` chama `inverte`. Aqui, a última posição válida para a palavra `anna` é `3`, pois ela tem comprimento 4 e C começa strings na posição 0:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>


    int inverte (char *n, int y, int aux) {
        if (y <= aux) return 1;
        else {
            if (n[y] != n[aux]) return 0;

            return inverte(n, y-1, aux+1);
        } 
    }

     int palindromo (char *n) {
        int aux1, x = 0;

        aux1 = inverte(n, strlen(n) - 1, x);

        if (aux1 == 1) printf("Eh palindromo\n");
        else printf("Nao eh palindromo\n");

     }


     int main() {
        palindromo("banana");
        palindromo("anna");
        palindromo("ana");
        palindromo("bananab");
        palindromo("aa");
        palindromo("a");

        return 0; 
     }
```

Vejo no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/rFymmf)

### Sugestão 2: `y` é o índice que indica o caracter logo depois do último válido

Nessa sugestão, mudei a interpretação de `y`: agora, `y` sempre será o índice depois do último caracter válido. Então, a chamada de `palindromo` continua idêntica, porém mudei quem estava sendo comparada na comparação de `inverte`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


int inverte (char *n, int y, int aux) {
    if (y <= aux) return 1;
    else {
        if (n[y - 1] != n[aux]) return 0;

        return inverte(n, y-1, aux+1);
    } 
}

 int palindromo (char *n) {
    int aux1, x = 0;

    aux1 = inverte(n, strlen(n), x);

    if (aux1 == 1) printf("Eh palindromo\n");
    else printf("Nao eh palindromo\n");

 }


 int main() {
    palindromo("banana");
    palindromo("anna");
    palindromo("ana");
    palindromo("bananab");
    palindromo("aa");
    palindromo("a");

    return 0; 
 }
```

Vejo no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/XdrQjM)

Comment: Já tinha resolvido, acabei fazendo como a sua primeira solução, usando (strlen - 1), acabei trocando tmb o nome da função inverte, pra ficar mais claro chamei ela de 'compara'.

Comment: Muito bom xD Acho que você deveria marcar a resposta da Taisbevalle como a resposta, já que pelo que entendi foi a resposta dela que te ajudou

Answer (score 3):

Seu código está confuso, tem muito `if` "solto", uma dica é utilizar as chaves `{}` para separar, na minha opinião fica melhor a visualização.

Como no comentário você disse que está um pouco perdido na recursão, vou te mostrar uma forma de fazer (não é a única). No código abaixo você digita a palavra que você quer e ele retorna se é ou não palíndromo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Função recursiva para verificar se a palavra é palíndromo
int palindromo(char palavra[], int tam, int posicao) {

    if (posicao < tam / 2){
        if (palavra[posicao] == palavra[tam - posicao - 1]){
            return 1 * palindromo(palavra, tam, posicao+1);
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else{
        return 1;
    }
}

int main() {

   char palavra[255];
   int tam;

   printf ("Digite a palavra: \n");   
   gets(palavra); // Ler a palavra digitada pelo usuário

   tam = strlen(palavra); // Tamanho da palavra

   if (palindromo(palavra, tam, 0))
      printf("É palíndromo\n");
   else
      printf("Não é palíndromo\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/okxnOz).

Usando a função `int palindromo (char *n)` você pode fazer conforme o código abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Função recursiva para verificar se a palavra é palíndromo
int inverte(char *n, int tam, int posicao){

    if (posicao < tam / 2){
        if (n[posicao] == n[tam - posicao - 1]){
            return 1 * inverte(n, tam, posicao+1);
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else{
        return 1;
    }
}

int palindromo(char *n) { 

    int aux1, x = 0;

    aux1 = inverte(n, strlen(n), x);

    if (aux1 == 1) printf("Eh palindromo");
    else printf("Nao eh palindromo");

}

int main() {

    char m[30] = {"teste"};
    palindromo(m);

    return 0;
}
```

Só modifiquei a sua função `inverte`.

Veja no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/Aa7SKo).

Comment: "int palindromo(char palavra[], int tam, int posicao)" (infelizmente não posso fazer isso na função) o parametro de função é "int palindromo (char *n)", por isso usei duas funções, passando o tamanho e um auxiliar pra função inverte

Comment: @MarcelodeSousa, editei a resposta.

Comment: o programa só tem como respostas "Eh palindromo", mesmo não sendo

Comment: @MarcelodeSousa, agora está correto.

Answer (score -4):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int pali(char palavra[], int tam, int i)
{
    if(i > tam/2)

        return 1;

    if(palavra[i] == palavra[(tam-1)-i])

        return pali(palavra, tam, i+1);

    else return -1;
}

int main()
{
    char palavra[15];
    int tam = 0;

    scanf("%s", &palavra);

    tam = strlen(palavra);

    // retorna 1 caso seja palindromo e -1 caso n seja
    if(pali(palavra, tam, 0) > 0)

        printf("A palavra %s e palindromo", palavra);

    else

     printf("A palavra %s nao e palindromo", palavra);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em português. Sempre que possível, tente explicar o pensamento que o levou a essa resposta. E quando responde em uma pergunta antiga já respondida, tente apresentar algo novo perante as outras respostas.